# npm facebook-node-sdk not found error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gulp

I am getting an error in node js even though I have the facebook-node-sdk. The error days that the basefacebook.js is not found even though the file is in the correct file path.

I am using gulp for development. I am using in React, which shouldn't matter. Could is be gulp issue? What am I missing

// app.jsx

```
var React = require('react');
var Facebook = require('facebook-node-sdk');
```

[image: The file exist]
[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

At the github page for facebook-node-sdk;

npm install fb

var FB = require('fb');